# How to launch a desktop application from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know if it is technical possible and how to:

- Open a GUI desktop application from a Node app.
- Wrap a GUI desktop application within a Node app.

Could http://electron.atom.io/  be used to work out this use-cases?

Platform Window 8.1 / 10.

Comment: Sure it's possible, although which platform(s) are you referring to specifically?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I am interested primary on WIN platform.

Comment: I was about to say `child_process`. This is a dupplicate.

Comment: This is both duplicate and too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first point, here is nodes documentation using the node module child_process on how to do it: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process